# conver powershell script to csv

Tags: powershell

im doing some testing with powershell to list hardware information of each computer in my domain. my script will get a list of computer from a text file that i created using powershell.

```
$arrComputers = get-Content -Path "C:\powershell\List.txt"
foreach ($strComputer in $arrComputers)
{
    $colItemsOs = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_OperatingSystem" -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
    -computername $strComputer
   foreach ($objItem in $colItemsOs)
   {
    Write-host  "Computer Name: " $strComputer
    Write-host  "OsName: " $objItem.Name
    Write-host  "Version: " $objItem.Version
   }

    $colItemsCompsys = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_ComputerSystem" -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
    -computername $strComputer
   foreach ($objItem in $colItemsCompsys)
   {
    Write-host  "Memory: " $objItem.TotalPhysicalMemory
    Write-host  "Manufacturer: " $objItem.Manufacturer
    Write-host  "Model: " $objItem.Model
    Write-host  "Domain: " $objItem.Domain
   }



     $colItemsSysEnc = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_SystemEnclosure" -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
    -computername $strComputer
   foreach ($objItem in $colItemsSysEnc)
   {
    Write-host  "SerialNumber: " $objItem.SerialNumber
   }

     $colItemsProcessor = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_Processor" -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
    -computername $strComputer
   foreach ($objItem in $colItemsProcessor)
   {
    Write-host  "Processor: " $objItem.Name
   }

    $colItemsIP = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration " -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
    -computername $strComputer -Filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"
   foreach ($objItem in $colItemsIP)
   {
    Write-host  "IPAddress: " $objItem.IpAddress
   }

    Write-host | Out-File c:\powershell\reportbeta.csv

}
```

however, i am unable to do so. how do i produce the result in csv file which will be able to be uploaded to my database using sqlcmd later on.

what am i missing out?

thank you

---

ive managed to display output in text file. however, only 1 record is displayed.

```
$arrComputers = get-Content -Path "C:\powershell\List.txt"
foreach ($strComputer in $arrComputers)
{
    $colItemsOs = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_OperatingSystem" -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
    -computername $strComputer
   foreach ($objItem in $colItemsOs)
   {
      $strComputer
      $Name =$objItem.Name
      $Version = $objItem.Version
   }

    $colItemsCompsys = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_ComputerSystem" -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
    -computername $strComputer
   foreach ($objItem in $colItemsCompsys)
   {
      $TotalMemory = $objItem.TotalPhysicalMemory
      $Manufacturer = $objItem.Manufacturer
      $Model = $objItem.Model
      $Domain = $objItem.Domain
   }



     $colItemsSysEnc = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_SystemEnclosure" -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
    -computername $strComputer
   foreach ($objItem in $colItemsSysEnc)
   {
      $SerialNUmber = $objItem.SerialNumber
   }

     $colItemsProcessor = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_Processor" -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
    -computername $strComputer
   foreach ($objItem in $colItemsProcessor)
   {
     $Processor = $objItem.Name
   }

    $colItemsIP = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration " -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
    -computername $strComputer -Filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"
   foreach ($objItem in $colItemsIP)
   {
      $IPV4 = $objItem.IpAddress
   }

    $OutputObj  = New-Object -Type PSObject
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $strComputer.ToUpper()


    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Name 
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Version -Value $Version
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TotalPhysicalMemory -Value $TotalMemory 
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Manufacturer -Value $Manufacturer
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Model -Value $Model

    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Processor -Value $ProcessorSpeed
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SerialNumber -Value $SerialNo
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Domain -Value $Domain
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value $IPV4 
    $OutputObj | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation "c:\powershell\report.txt"

}
```

im out of ideas now. should i make it into array like?

please advise.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are exporting to csv within the loop, so the last item will be the only one showing. Try something like this.

Before the loop:

```
# Create empty array
$report = @()
```

At the end of the loop, in place of where you are currently exporting to CSV:

```
#Add item to report
$report += $OutputObj
```

Finally, after the end of the loop:

```
$report | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation "c:\powershell\report.txt"
```

Comment: thanks alot kevin. u just save me a couple of hours figuring out how to list pso object using add-content to generate my list.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you assign the foreach result to a variable then pipe it to `Export-Csv`. It should perform faster and is much efficient than recreating, and updating, an array in each loop iteration.

```
$result = foreach($strComputer in $arrComputers)...

$result | Export-CSV ...
```

If you used the `Foreach-Object' cmdlet to loop over computers you could skip the whole assignment or array creation, processing one object at a time (streamlined) and pipe directly to`Export-CSV`:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\powershell\List.txt | Foreach-Object{
    ...
} | Export-Csv ...
```